# Split single run of `dbt materialize` by temporal field and commit them separately

Tags: postgresql, dbt, dbt-postgres

i'm using `dbt` to materialize a table on a `postgresql`. this table has a temporal field (`timestamp`).

the problem is that when this table is being created for the first time `dbt` runs all of it using a single sql query (as defined in my model) and it gets timed out as it exceeds `statement_timeout`, and no data is inserted in the table even as a lot of proccessing has been done.

is there any solution which breaks up the data into several steps and commits each step as it gets completed? this way the `dbt run` would still take a long time but each step is a separate query and it wouldn't surpass `statement_timeout`

i know about the `incremental` option of `dbt` and i use it in next runs, but my problem is about the initial run.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

> is there any solution which breaks up the data into several steps and commits each step as it gets completed?

Currently there is **no dbt native solution** to do so. As you said, it will open one transaction to create your whole table.
You can have a look at [Custom materialisation](https://docs.getdbt.com/guides/create-new-materializations?step=1) to code your own behaviour but i guess it will be quite difficult.

> i know about the incremental option of dbt and i use it in next runs, but my problem is about the initial run.

I guess you have **the right solution using incremental**. A little tips maybe to achieve what you want and **avoid loading the whole table during the first run** is to use a combinaison of **LIMIT and ORDER BY**, something like that :

```
{% if is_incremental() %}

  -- this filter will only be applied on an incremental run
  where id::int >= (select max(id) from {{ this }})
  ORDER BY id ASC
  limit 1000

{% else %}

ORDER BY id ASC
LIMIT 1000

{% endif %}
```

This way, the first time you run your model it will load the 1000 rows, then every next run you will load the next 1000 rows. You can adapt it to your need, its a way to simulate breaking the data into "multiple steps".

Comment: thank you i think your solution works but the problem is that when you several materialized models that are dependent on each other, this solution may cause the data in the downstream models to be wrong. e.g. the first table has a record for each day, the later table aggregates it for each month & ...

Comment: True, in that case, either you can find a way to not build downstream models until your upstream model is completed (just run manually your pipeline at the beginning then once its completed you orchestrate it?), or you have to adapt the previous code to make it "smarter", like not use "LIMIT 1000" but the data related to 1 month if feasible, that way you keep consistency in your downstream models